# What is the function of diode and capacitor in RS232 shifter circuit?

Tags: capacitor, diodes, rs232, ttl

as shown in the picture, can anyone explain the capacitor and diode in detail? Thank you!
[image]

Comment: I want to say those are what create the negative supply for the RS232 signal.  Take a look at this article: http://www.uchobby.com/index.php/2007/06/11/ttl-to-rs232-adaptor-explained/

Comment: See also [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/339528/capacitor-in-rs232-level-shifter-data-is-strictly-half-duplex/339565#339565).

Comment: @LFJY: can you post the value of Vcc. Is it 12V?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RS232 logic levels are (from memory)

- high: -12 to -3 V.
- low: +3 to +12 V.

Since your level shifter is interfacing with a device with only a single-ended, positive supply there is a problem sending out a high signal on RX-RS232.

The trick here is to steal some power from the TX signal of the other device when it is high (negative). The diode charges the capacitor to a negative voltage and this is used to bias the RX line negative if the TX-TTL signal is high (which will turn the PNP transistor off).

[image]

When the TX-TTL signal is high and the PNP turned off there is a potential divider formed between the three 10k resistors, 1, 2 & 3. The best that can be obtained from this arrangement is that the RX line will be a little more positive (due to the diode drop) than \$ \frac {2}{3}V_{TX} \$. If V<sub>TX</sub> is weak (close to -3 V) this circuit may not work as the voltage to the other device's RX will be out of specification.

Comment: I've written up a little something [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/339528/capacitor-in-rs232-level-shifter-data-is-strictly-half-duplex/339565#339565). Feel free to use, borrow, whatever you find useful from it.

Comment: More like a technical treatise with history of serial comms and personal projects thrown in. +1, as usual.

Comment: What can I say? ;)

Comment: Good analysis. I Remember that RS-232 Rx threshold is same as TTL or two diode drops 1.4V so lots of margin with dwell on Idle V- but less if continuous $FF stop repeat

Comment: Hence, when you have to charge the RX-line caps it could be happen that the caps gets totally discharged? Further if VCC is 5V and you would like to send a logic 0, you would have a 4.8V at the collector, and RX would be -4.8V. But it should be >3V???

Comment: Your last point is a good one. With the collector at 4.8 V the RX line would be at the mid-point of the R1, R2 divider. R2 should probably be a lower value - say 1k.

Comment: @Transistor: it's better to use nmost, and more better to use  a R232 chip that provides output-signals of -12/12V with a 5V supply! They use a charge pump to get these levels! I don't know if I'm allowed here to make advertising, but the Max232 is famous for this.

Comment: I first used the MAX232 in about 1993. No messing about!

Comment: To those who've only experienced the MAX232 and subsequent devices for RS-232 support, I encourage them to try out an MC1488 and MC1489, someday, and see what RS-232 IC life was like *before*. Jim T. designed those in the mid 1960's, working at Motorola SPD (Phoenix.) The MAX232 arrived in 1987! Amazingly late, being about two decades later and arguably when RS-232 was already on its way out. We could have used it at least a decade earlier, I think. Very late in coming.

Comment: @Transistor Can I ask a quick question? Is that practical if I simply use two inverters to convert between RS232 and TTL?

Comment: No. Look at the logic levels. You need to get a negative voltage out. That's the whole problem and the reason for the level shifter. I think you need to read it all again!

Comment: @Transistor Yea! I realized it after I sent out this question... Thank you!